# Code check in in TFS without a new changeset

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am new to TFS.I had checked in the code through VS 2015 in TFS.A changeset was generated.
Now I need to edit the code and check in with the earlier changeset.Is there any way I can edit the code without a new changeset getting created.

Answer (score 0):

No. TFVC check-ins are immutable and cannot be rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

When you check in your changes, they are stored on the server as a changeset. **TFS creates a changeset every time you do a checkin**. All the files that are checked in together are included in the changeset. Changesets **contain the history of each item** in version control. And history in TFS is immutable.

You could go through this blog [TFS Basics–Changeset](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dajung/2013/04/17/tfs-basicschangeset/) for more detail concept of it.